# Button to get me to an <div id= doesn't work

Tags: html

I just want that when I press `Submit` button to get me to the `<div id="Home>` where the other code will be.

This is my work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>MyWebsite</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Start" align="center">
        <h1 style="color:red">My</style><span style="color:blue">Website</span></h1>
        <hr/>
        Name:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
        Password:<br/>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br/><br/>
        <form action="Home">
            <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="Home" align="center">
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You do realise `div`s are not separate pages, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some PHP (or other server side language) between your form and the div below it. Otherwise you're just refreshing the page when you hit submit.

You could also use javascript/jQuery.

Try doing one or both of the above and then come back for help if you have trouble.

Comment: I suspect the OP doesn't know anything about JS, let alone PHP. The way the question is worded it sounds like they think they can "load" a div as if it were a whole page.

Comment: I actually meant to leave this as a comment, not an answer. But you could be right. He needs to investigate it. There are hundreds of tutorials out there on forms.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer, I didn't know it was impossible to do that without having JS or PHP...Anyway, thank you!